# Searching one array and displaying the value of another array at same index

Tags: iphone, objective-c, internationalization

Here is my plist:

```
<dict>
 <key>ehindi</key>
 <string>ankamaal</string>
 <key>part</key>
 <string>n</string>
 <key>meaning</key>
 <string>hug</string>
 <key>hindi</key>
 <string>अंकमाल </string>
</dict>
```

Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSString *finalPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"];
    NSDictionary *plistData = [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:finalPath]
        retain];

    NSArray *inHidi = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[dict valueForKey:@"hindi"]];
    NSDictionary *inHindiDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:inHindi    
        forKey:@"HindiArray"];

    NSArray *inEhindi = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[dict valueForKey:@"ehindi"]];
    NSDictionary *inEhindiDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:inEhindi 
        forKey:@"EHindiArray"];

    [listItem addObject:inEhindiDict];
    [listItem addObject:inHindiDict];

    copyItem = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    /////....
}
```

I'trying to search key 'ehindi' and display 'hindi' result on my screen. Here What i did to search

```
 - (void) searchTableView {
     NSString *searchText = searchBar.text;
     NSMutableArray *searchArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

     for (NSDictionary *dictionary in listItems)
     {
         NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"EHindiArray"];
         [searchArray addObjectsFromArray:array];
     }

     for (NSString *sTemp in searchArray)
     {
         NSRange titleResultsRange = [sTemp rangeOfString:searchText 
             options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

        if (titleResultsRange.length > 0)
            [copyItem addObject:sTemp];
     }

     [searchArray release];
     searchArray = nil;
 }
```

I am just able to search 'ehindi'. How can i find the and display the word in 'hindi'. It is not possible to search devnagari and only option I have is to find the index and dispay the value of that index of "EHindiArray".... I will be really happy if someone could help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in Objective-C. The way you are asking your question "Searching on array and displaying the value of another at the same index" sounds like these are *parallel arrays*.

Can you not simply store the index of the one array and use that variable to display the value of the other?

I may misunderstanding how the plist comes into play here but...

On the other hand, it looks like you are creating a dictionary. Why use the dictionary object for this? You could make your own custom `HindiWord` class and have strings for each of your dictionary entries. It would be something like:

```
#import <Foundation/NSObject.h>

@interface HindiWord: NSObject {
    NSString ehindi;
    NSString part;
    NSString meaning;
    NSString hindi;
}

@end
```

You'd then have 1 array of these objects, and you could search for the ehindi string, and easily grab the hindi string.